# Why is sudo apt update not working?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, ppa

For the past while, I've been trying to run `sudo apt update` so I can prep my computer to upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10. However, every time I run it, I get a combination of these types of errors:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/audacity/ubuntu focal InRelease: Couldn't execute /usr/bin/apt-key to check /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntuhandbook1_audacity_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxmint-tr/araclar/ubuntu focal InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxmint-tr/araclar/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease: Couldn't execute /usr/bin/apt-key to check /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-updates_InRelease
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.bintray.com/scratux/stable/dists/focal/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 34.214.192.151 443]
```

There are tons of these types of errors every time I run it. What's going on, and how can I fix it?

Here's the full output of my command:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PziOBmZn1L1A0AuH5rc7jSiCDQLBSdmdv62VIagRh60/edit?usp=sharing

Note: sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:(ppa that needs to be removed) only works for some of these errors, and even then it doesn't always work.

Comment: Sadly, no. There are a variety of errors that I don't think it will work for, and sometimes even the error in that question isn't fixed by this.

Comment: Obviously you have some PPAs that need to be removed. All errors are about that. So it's a dupe.

Comment: Removing the old PPAs that don't have content for your release or no longer exist is a step forward. If you still have error **after** removing the wrong PPAs, according to the duplicate, then please show us the new results.

Comment: You should always include the entire output of commands you post here. If you post bits and pieces we aren't seeing the whole picture. Edit your question and replace the whole output.

Comment: Remove all PPAs mentioned. You can do it from Software & Updates app. `add-apt-repository` won't remove some of these because they are not from launchpad.